# Is an ellipsoid a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to appeal to the Hopf-Rinow theorem to show that there exists a minimal geodesic connecting any two points $p,q$ on the ellipsoid, i.e. the set

$$  \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

I do not any formal training in Differential Geometry, so I have been following Do Carmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces".

In particular, his statement of Hopf-Rinow theorem in section 5.3 is that if $S$ is a complete surface, then given two points $p,q \in S$, there exists a minimal geodesic joining $p$ to $q$.

The corollary above the Hopf-Rinow theorem states that if a surface is compact then it is complete. I think that one can use the Heine-Borel theorem to prove that the ellipsoid is a compact surface and thus appeal to the Hopf-Rinow theorem.

However, when I consulted other resources, I read that there was an additional condition that the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ must be Riemannian. For example, on Wikipedia it states that the Clifton-Pohl torus is an example of a manifold that is compact but not complete.

This brings me to the following question, if we have that $a,b,c \in R \setminus \{0\}$, the ellipsoid is in general a Riemannian manifold?

Comment: It’s a smooth manifold! So then…

Comment: The Riemannian metric is induced from the usual metric on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @FedePoncio every smooth manifold has a Riemannian metric. Thank you to everyone that answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Yes.

A Riemannian manifold is a smooth manifold equiped with a Riemannian metric (a smooth "law of scalar products of tangent vectors"). Every smooth submanifold of any Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be equiped with a Riemannian metric induced by $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence, it can also be regarded as a Riemannian manifold. In particular, if you choose to use Euclidean distance to define your length-minimizing curve, then it is fine to suppose that your ellipsoid is a Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
For Clifton-Pohl torus, it is a compact manifold whose metric is deliberately chosen to have pathological properties ( so the metric here is not necessarily a Riemannian metric).